# Asp.net gridview export to excel formatting issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, gridview

I have created a simple application while will export data into excel. Now the data is exported to excel successfully but it will show an exception of formatting when I opened the downloaded excel.

```
public ActionResult ExportOrder()
            {
                List<OrderItem> data = new List<OrderItem>();            

                GridView gv = new GridView();
                gv.DataSource = data;
                gv.DataBind();
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Common.GenerateSerialNo() + ".xls");
                Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
                Response.Charset = "";
                StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
                gv.RenderControl(htw);
                Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();

                return RedirectToAction("OrderProducts");
            }
```

This is my formatting issue while opening in Excel.
[Format Issue Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nukbv.jpg)

Please suggest me to solve this issue.

I tried but found solutions to use NPOI or other Paid Tools. Can we solve the formatting issue without using any third party tool. I also tried some solutions but it didn't work for me.

Comment: what's data type of Contact number column List<OrderItem>?

Comment: What is the type of `OrderItem.Contact_No`?

Comment: Start using a specialized library for creating Excel files, like [EPPlus](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/epplus/drafts/98280) for example. All you are doing now is creating a HTML page with an .xls extension.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the style on data bound not when doing the export as follows

```
private void gvPrint_RowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
        e.Row.Cells(0).Attributes.Add("class", "text");
        e.Row.Cells(1).Attributes.Add("class", "text");
        e.Row.Cells(2).Attributes.Add("class", "text");
        e.Row.Cells(6).Attributes.Add("class", "text");
        e.Row.Cells(7).Attributes.Add("class", "text");
        e.Row.Cells(8).Attributes.Add("class", "text");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, i am not using any gridview in code. i am making a gridview on exporting time.